# Rails + postgres: Using Group query on a has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by

I'm struggling with understanding how `group` works in Rails. There doesn't really appear to be any good tutorials either...

```
class Doctor
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment
  has_many :doctors
  has_many :patients
end

class Patient
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end
```

The `Doctor` class has a field `primary_doctor`. A `patient` can have many `doctors`, but only one `primary_doctor`.

Given a specific `doctor`, I want a list of all `patients` that doctor sees, grouped by the `primary_doctor` for each `patient`.

```
doctor.patients.joins(:appointments).where(appointments: { is_primary: true }).group("patients.id, appointments.doctor_id")
```

is what I feel should work, but that doesn't do any grouping. If I add a `.count` to the end, it almost gives me what I want, but instead of the actual objects, I get a hash of `{doctor_id=>patient_count}`.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to `select` the fields you need after grouping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to be using Ruby's in-memory `group_by` function. Unless I've missed something the last 10 years, ActiveRecord can't marshal a database query straight into the type of representation you're looking for.

So, to get a list of all patients that doctor sees, grouped by the `primary_doctor` for each patient, you could do:

```
doctor.patients.joins(:appointments).where(appointments: { is_primary: true }).
  group_by(&:primary_doctor)
```

This would give you a result like:

```
{
  <Doctor id: 1, name: "Dr Bob"> =>
    [<Patient id: 1, name: "Joe">,
     <Patient id: 2, name: "Jane">],
  <Doctor id: 2, name: "Dr Spock"> =>
    [<Patient id: 3, name: "Jack">,
     <Patient id: 4, name: "Jill">,
     <Patient id: 5, name: "Scotty">]
}
```

Note, this might be mildly inefficient if you have to go back to the database each time to get the primary_doctor, so if this is a critical path in your app you will probably also use `includes` (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) somewhere in there.

Comment: Are you sure about this? The API documentation says its quite possible to get a collection of records. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group

Comment: The collection returned by AR is a single-dimensional array, even in the documentation you linked to, except sometimes in some edge cases like `count`. You stated you'd like a map (so in Ruby, a hash structure) of primary doctor to an array of patients. SQL `group` is for compiling many rows into a single representation *before* marshalling; that's not what you asked for here, at least.

Comment: Added sample output to my answer so you can see how it's different than the AR documentation and whether it's what you meant.

Comment: Beautiful, `group_by` is what I need. So `group` is really only used for aggregate functions (sum, avg, etc)?

Comment: Personally, yes. I recently used it as part of a query to find duplicate records, as another example, but in my experience it's extremely uncommon in standard CRUD operations (as your example seems to be a part of).